# How can I access other derived classes from another derived class?

Tags: c#, oop

I have classes A1, A2, A3, A4 derived from a class A.  How can I access the other classes from another derived class (I need to access A2 or A3 or A4 from class A1)?

A condition is that I will not have the other class instances as members. Is there any way?

Comment: What do you mean by "access the other classes"? You need instance references, you want to know they types and access static stuff? Or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without creating instance, you can
 only access static members of that
 class. So if you want to access any
method without creating instance you
 should keep that member as static.

Comment: If you're going to quote something, you should provide a source. If it's not a quote, you probably shouldn't mark it up as one :)